# how can use Persian tts example in android?

Tags: android

how can use Persian tts example in android?
i want an android TTS for Persian languages
this is my example but in android we don't have all languages
what can i do?

```
myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently persian (farsi) added to espeak project. 
As I know, espeak is open source and work also in android.

Answer (score 0):

To fine  whether a specific language is supported, use isLanguageAvailable(), which returns the level of support for the given language.
Example:

```
myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.PERSIAN))
```

If supported, it will return as follows:

```
TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE
```

Comment: but i cannot set it as my tts

Comment: myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.PERSIAN); have err

Comment: if(myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.PERSIAN)==TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
    myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.PERSIAN);

Comment: Check out this link, http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html

Comment: The above answer is incorrect. There is no TTS support for Persian on android.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the persian version of Espeak for android. You can install it through adb. If you don't have access to adb through shell. Here is a guide for windows: 
http://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

persian version of http://irtbc.ir/d/3829878

How to install espeak on android. 
https://github.com/rhdunn/espeak#android

To install through adb type `adb install espak.apk`

Comment: Android doesn't have support for Persian TTS, so not sure what code you are looking for.

Comment: The original question is about using Persian TTS in code . You have referred to an opensource library but didn't provide any link to a project or mention any code. instead you provided a link to an apk which is not desired for programmers !