# How can I add new languages to google's TTS API?

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech, persian

I am trying to use google TTS inside my Android app. Within this part of my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status)
    {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.);
            if(result==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
            {
                Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
            }
            else{
                ConvertTextToSpeech();
            }
        }
        else
            Log.e("error", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
});
```

In this line `int result=tts.setLanguage(Locale.);`  I am trying to use `Locale.fa_IR` But it says `Error:(37, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable fa_IR`. How can I fix this?

I think I should install something on the emulator, but don't know what, and how?

Answer (score 1):

because     `Locale.fa_IR` is not a language understand by **Text To Speech**.
To Know how many language it supoort. Just do one thing.

```
tts.setLanguage(Locale.);
```

after Locale dot you get multiple option so the only set of language suppoted shown there choose whichever country language you want to support in you application

Comment: So it means there is no way to add this language to supported list?

Comment: No, That's a in build functionality which cannot be changed.

Comment: Thank you!
Do you know any alternative TTS for Persian with a sample code to learn how to use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029523/how-can-use-persian-tts-example-in-android this might help you

Answer (score 0):

Use language code from https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp.

```
mLanguage = new Locale(language_codes);

tts = new TextToSpeech(mContext, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                int result = tts.setLanguage(mLanguage);
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("Text2SpeechWidget", result + " is not supported");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `mLanguage` ?

Comment: **mLanguage = new Locale(language_codes);**
and language_codes from w3schools site

Comment: I can't understand the relation between `TTS` and `HTML` codes

Comment: Just ISO 639-1 Language Codes, not **html**.